# Insert into select nested select (s) performance. Huge union selection

Tags: postgresql

I have more, than a hundred simple similar to each other tables, named 'fw_1', 'fw_2', ... and so on with absolutely simple structure, based on following SQL:

```sql
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE public.fw_1 (
    combi_id int8 NOT NULL,
    combos_1 int4[] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fw_1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (combi_id)
);
```

Those tables popullated with array-data of integers data-type.

I have other table, named 'fw_final':

```sql
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE public.fw_final (
    combi_id bigserial NOT NULL,
    combos1_1 int4[] NULL,
    combos2_2 int4[] NULL,
    --... iteratively the same (ommited for brevity)
    combos160_160 int4[] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT fw_final_pkey null
);
```

, where code performs following INSERT INTO SELECT with a lot of nested SELECTs, united by UNION ALL command:

```sql
INSERT INTO fw_final (combos1_1, combos2_2, /*...iteratively the same, ommited for brevity...*/, combos160_160)
SELECT
    (SELECT combos_1 FROM fw_1 WHERE combi_id=1),
    (SELECT combos_1 FROM fw_2 WHERE combi_id=1),
    --iteratively the same, ommited for brevity
    (SELECT combos_1 FROM fw_160 WHERE combi_id=1)
UNION ALL
SELECT
    (SELECT combos_1 FROM fw_1 WHERE combi_id=2),
    (SELECT combos_1 FROM fw_2 WHERE combi_id=2),
    --iteratively the same, ommited for brevity
    (SELECT combos_1 FROM fw_160 WHERE combi_id=2)

--... iteratively the same, ommited for brevity

UNION ALL
SELECT
    (SELECT combos_1 FROM fw_1 WHERE combi_id=160),
    (SELECT combos_1 FROM fw_2 WHERE combi_id=160),
    --iteratively the same, ommited for brevity
    (SELECT combos_1 FROM fw_160 WHERE combi_id=160)
```

**Issue**:

**Actual**: This part of code executes relatively very long time, about 8 seconds and few milliseconds more or less

**Expected: less than a second**

Please, suggest/recommend some workarounds etc. how to improve/increase performance for the task for putting data into last table from the other ones? Should I use COPY FROM (SELECT ..., ...) TO STDOUT command somehow to collect selection data first on external side for further COPY fw_final FROM STDIN? But selection itself takes equivalent long time.

EXPLAIN ANALYSE of above code in PgAdmin 4 returns following:
QUERY PLAN

```
Insert on fw_final  (cost=1306.91..131011.25 rows=100 width=10728) (actual time=285.439..285.439 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Result  (cost=1306.91..131011.25 rows=100 width=10728) (actual time=2.177..142.461 rows=100 loops=1)
        ->  Append  (cost=1306.91..130693.75 rows=100 width=5120) (actual time=1.951..138.648 rows=100 loops=1)
              ->  Result  (cost=1306.91..1306.92 rows=1 width=5120) (actual time=1.949..1.949 rows=1 loops=1)
                    InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
                      ->  Index Scan using fw_1_pkey on fw_1  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.083..0.084 rows=1 loops=1)
                            Index Cond: (combi_id = 1)
--...
              ->  Result  (cost=1306.91..1306.92 rows=1 width=5120) (actual time=1.369..1.370 rows=1 loops=1)
--...
Planning Time: 3291.243 ms
Execution Time: 4122.017 ms
```

---

**Misc**: CPU FX8320 8cores, 16GB RAM, Two classic HDD 5400/7200 RPM

---

---

**UPDATE**:

```sql
INSERT INTO fw_final (combos1_1, combos2_1, /*...iteratively the same, ommited for brevity...*/, combos160_1)
SELECT
    (SELECT combos_1 FROM fw_1 WHERE combi_id=${SUBSTITUTED_FROM_OTHER_SOURCE_THAN_SQL}),
    (SELECT combos_1 FROM fw_2 WHERE combi_id=${SUBSTITUTED_FROM_OTHER_SOURCE_THAN_SQL}),
    --iteratively the same, ommited for brevity
    (SELECT combos_1 FROM fw_160 WHERE combi_id=${SUBSTITUTED_FROM_OTHER_SOURCE_THAN_SQL})
UNION ALL
SELECT
    (SELECT combos_1 FROM fw_1 WHERE combi_id=${SUBSTITUTED_FROM_OTHER_SOURCE_THAN_SQL}),
    (SELECT combos_1 FROM fw_2 WHERE combi_id=${SUBSTITUTED_FROM_OTHER_SOURCE_THAN_SQL}),
    --iteratively the same, ommited for brevity
    (SELECT combos_1 FROM fw_160 WHERE combi_id=${SUBSTITUTED_FROM_OTHER_SOURCE_THAN_SQL})

--... iteratively the same, ommited for brevity

UNION ALL
SELECT
    (SELECT combos_1 FROM fw_1 WHERE combi_id=${SUBSTITUTED_FROM_OTHER_SOURCE_THAN_SQL}),
    (SELECT combos_1 FROM fw_2 WHERE combi_id=${SUBSTITUTED_FROM_OTHER_SOURCE_THAN_SQL}),
    --iteratively the same, ommited for brevity
    (SELECT combos_1 FROM fw_160 WHERE combi_id=${SUBSTITUTED_FROM_OTHER_SOURCE_THAN_SQL})
```

*Please note*:
Number of source data-tables 'fw_XYZ' == 'combosXYZ_1' (number of columns in 'fw_final')
**BUT! Number of outer selects may vary**

**Same issue remains**

Comment: Sorry, fixed misstyped

Comment: A full outer join maybe? https://rextester.com/RVMTWZ94983

Comment: Despite on strict digit typing. This code works but very slow IMO

Comment: Will try and let you know if it helps

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you. Works for initial question. I have updated the question. Are there any solutions for this?

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like that firstly (untested):

```
INSERT INTO fw_final (combos1_1, combos2_2, /*...iteratively the same, ommited for brevity...*/, combos160_160)
select
  fw_1.combi_1,
  fw_2.combi_1,
  /*...iteratively the same, ommited for brevity...*/
  fw_160.combi_1
from
  generate_series(1, 160) AS ids(combi_id)
  left join fw_1 on fw_1.combi_id = ids.combi_id
  left join fw_2 on fw_2.combi_id = ids.combi_id
  /*...iteratively the same, ommited for brevity...*/
  left join fw_160 on fw_160.combi_id = ids.combi_id
```

**Edit:**

If IDs are not sequential, and you want to generate in the same way as the parts of the query, you should substitute:

```
  generate_series(1, 160) AS ids(combi_id)
```

with:

```
(
 select 1 combi_id
 union all
 select 2 combi_id
 union all
 select 3 combi_id
      /*...iteratively the same, ommited for brevity...*/
 union all
 select 160 combi_id
) ids
```

Comment: I generate series in outer java-code, so it passed in SQL-executor already pasted and generated. Not that point. Reason is that SQL-solution itself very slow, as mentioned in the topic

Comment: Did you try this and it was also slow?

Comment: Works fine, 
`INSERT 0 160
Query returned successfully in 1 secs 14 msec.`
**Thank you!** But **what if in my example**, key `combi_id` of nested queries would not be sequential series from nested line to other nested line, also plus number of outer "aggregate" selects != 160, but less or more than. The same time, number of input tables == number of columns in 'fw_final'. Saying simpler - it would not be a squared output table?

Comment: If I understood correctly, the answer is edited above.

Comment: Then UNION can be simplified to `from ( values (1), (2), ... (160) ) as combis(id)`

Comment: @manta 
@a_horse_with_no_name I figured out about `(values (x), (y), ...)` once, as @manta posted `generate_series` instead, **but**:
**Excuse me if I bring you wrong, misunderstanding**... In your solution, inserted output `fw_final` table is like a "square": number of rows == number of columns, and _for each new row, your code reuses same ids from previous row_, which are both wrong for my task in updated question. Pay attention, that **in my updated question example: Number of outer selects may vary. Each output row should not reuse previous row input ids**, it may differ. Thnx 4 patience